# How do I tile windows side by side?

Tags: 11.04, compiz

On the site http://ubuntued.info/como-por-as-janelas-do-ubuntu-lado-a-lado is possible to place the windows side by side with the gnome-do, but this tool does not work in the new Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal. How do I make this work in the new ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install [compiz-fusion-plugins-extra](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compiz-fusion-plugins-extra) [image: Install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra].The defaults in Ubuntu 11.04 involve Upper Left Corner, Left Edge, and Lower Left Corner being set to Left Half, and Upper Right Corner, Right Edge, and Lower Right Corner being set to Right Half.

Answer (score 12):

I would also recommend for a day or so you use this really really good guide which shows you how to use some of Unity's features to the maximum

It was created by Octavian Damiean and I have found it very useful. When you have memorised all of it ;) you can go back to your favourite wallpaper
[image]

Here is the link for it if the image does not work

[direct link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbjs0.png)

Comment: Holding down the Super (Windows) key brings that up too, but it would be handy to have it as a desktop background.

Comment: just what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Press and Hold the Super key(Windows Key) until you see a popup that shows all keyboard shortcuts you could use. 
There is not option to tile windows out of the box but you could use some of those combinations.